# Subset by function's variable using $variable

Tags: r, function, subset

I am having trouble to subset from a list using a variable of my function.

```
rankhospital <- function(state,outcome,num = "best") {

#code here

e3<-dataframe(...,state.name,...)


if (num=="worst"){ return(worst(state,outcome))
}else if((num%in%b=="TRUE" & outcome=="heart attack")=="TRUE"){
 sep<-split(e3,e3$state.name)
 hosp.estado<-sep$state
 hospital<-hosp.estado[num,1]
 return(as.character(hospital))
```

I split my data frame by state (which is a variable of my function) 
But `hosp.estado<-sep$state` doesn't work. I have also tried `as.data.frame.`

The function (rankhospital("NY"....) returns me a character(0).

When I feed the sep$state with sep$"NY" directly in code it works perfectly so I guess the problem is I can't use a function's variable to do this. Am I right? What could I use instead?

Thank you!!

Comment: Also, try `sep[['state']]`.

Comment: Also, your if-condition is needlessly complicated. `num %in% b & outcome=="heart attack"` would do just as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `state` is a variable in your function, you can refer to a column with the name given by `state` using: `sep[state]` or `sep[[state]]`. The first produces a data frame with one column named based on the value of `state`. The second produces an unnamed vector.

```
df=data.frame(NY=rnorm(10),CA=rnorm(10), IL=rnorm(10))
state="NY"
df[state]
#             NY
# 1  -0.79533912
# 2  -0.05487747
# 3   0.25014132
# 4   0.61824329
# 5  -0.17262350
# 6  -2.22390027
# 7  -1.26361438
# 8   0.35872890
# 9  -0.01104548
# 10 -0.94064916
df[[state]]
#  [1] -0.79533912 -0.05487747  0.25014132  0.61824329 -0.17262350 -2.22390027 -1.26361438  0.35872890 -0.01104548 -0.94064916

class(df[state])
# [1] "data.frame"

class(df[[state]])
# [1] "numeric"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to get the top hospital in a state.  You don't want to `split` here (see the result of `sep` to see what I mean).  Instead, use:

```
as.character(e3[e3$state.name==state, 1][num])
```

This hopefully does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need `sep[[state]]` instead of `sep$state` to get the data frame out of your `sep` `list`, which matches the `state` parameter of your function. Like this:

```
e3 <- read.csv("https://raw.github.com/Hindol/data-analysis-coursera/master/HW3/hospital-data.csv")

state <- "WY"
num <- 1:5

sep<-split(e3,e3$State)
hosp.estado<-sep[[state]]
hospital<-hosp.estado[num,1]
as.character(hospital)
# [1] "530002" "530006" "530008" "530010" "530011"
```